# Single view of ASP.NET web application won't load in Azure dev environment

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure

I am working on a web application, containing multiple views, that is using the ASP.NET framework for the backend and the Angular framework for the frontend. When running this web application on my local machine, every view loads without issue, returning the 200 - OK status. However, when I deploy and run my application in the Azure dev environment, one view is intermittently returning a 404 - Not Found status. All of the other views seem to be working fine, with the exception of this one.

Also, when I look at the console, it appears that the URL being requested by the front-end is the front-end URL, which it should not be requesting. It should be requesting the backend URL, which is what every other successful view is requesting.

Is there a general cause to this issue or do I need to provide more information regarding the code I am using? Thanks.

Comment: I guess I am just to the point of "I don't even know where to begin looking". What kind of information should I provide? This is a project I am working on but am also fairly unfamiliar with.

Comment: Well.. you have a specific view.. that requests an incorrect API endpoint if I understand you correctly..? Maybe look at the service that does that call..? And find out what the variables are that could cause it to request something incorrect. If you have problems tracking it down - imagine the darkness we’re in trying to help you out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything in the network but the app is working fine (example: no packet loss when your application's network traffic traverse public and private network) there are three possible causes

1. Client side lack of permission to access the object (please verify
   messages exchanged between azure and your the browser with chrome
   dev tools) and if is trueyou can you can configure Cross Origin
   Resource Sharing (CORS) for the storage service the Angular client
   is accessing;
2. Also is possible a SASAuthorizationError issue (Please check the
   SASAuthorizationError in the metrics. Fault is non zero. [Here is
   explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages))
3. last but not least please check in server-side logs if another
   process deleted your target before frontend app can access